# What technologies are there for formatted, structured data input and output?

Tags: java, sharepoint, grails, ms-word, infopath

I am working on a project here that ingests internal resumes from people at my company, strips out the skills and relevant content from them and stores it in a database. This was all done using docx4j and Grails. This required the resumes to first be submitted via a template that formatted everything just right so that the ingest tool knew what to look for to strip the data.

The 2nd portion of this, is what if we want to get out a "reduced" resume from the database. In other words, I want to search the uploaded content I now have, and only print out new resumes for people who have Java programming experience lets say. So I can go into my database, find the people who originally had java as a skill, and output a new set of resumes that are also still in a nice templated format, and only have the relevant info in them, instead of ALL the content.

I have been writing some software to do this in Java that will basically use a docx template, overwriting the items in customXML which are bound to the content controls in the doc, so the new data shows up and can eb saved as a new docx with that custom data.

This seems really cumbersome to me, and has some limitations. For one, lets say my template has a place for 3 Skills, and the particular person has 8 skills. There seems to be no good way to add those 5 additional skills to the docx other than painstakingly inserting the data with all of the formatting XML tags and such. This is a real pain, because if the template changes, I dont want to have to go back into my software and edit source code to change that additional data input XML tag to bold instead of italic.

I was doing some reading up on using Infopath to create a form that I could use to get the input, connecting to some sharepoint data source or something to store the stripped out data. However, I can't seem to find out if it is possible using sharepoint to get the data back out, in a nice formatted way. What would the general steps for this be? It seems like I couldnt find very much about this topic with any quick googling.

Thanks

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with java or grails, the setup for the question was largely unrelated to the question itself, and the question itself was somewhat vague. Perhaps you could cut out the first 4 paragraphs and elaborate a little more on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up the skills:

```
<skills>
  <skill>..</skill>
  <skill>..</skill>
```

and use a "repeat" content control pointing to the  container.  This would handle any number of `<skill>` entries.

Comment: Yes, I was reading on the other forum. This may be the way I go.